GradCam positional argument error in pytorch
With this code I made to create a GradCAM class in order to generate the heatmap values for my data:
class GradCAM:
    """
    Class for generating GradCAM heatmaps for interpreting convolutional neural networks.

    Args:
        model (nn.Module): PyTorch model for which GradCAM will be generated.

    Attributes:
        model (nn.Module): PyTorch model.
        gradients (torch.Tensor): Gradients of the target layer.
    """
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.gradients = None

    def backward_hook(self, module, grad_input, grad_output):
        """
        Hook function to capture gradients of the target layer.

        Args:
            module (nn.Module): Target layer module.
            grad_input (tuple of torch.Tensor): Gradients of the input.
            grad_output (tuple of torch.Tensor): Gradients of the output.
        """
        self.gradients = grad_output[0]

    def generate_heatmap(self, input_tensor, target_layer_index):
        """
        Generate GradCAM heatmap.

        Args:
            input_tensor (torch.Tensor): Input tensor.
            target_layer_index (int): Index of the target layer.

        Returns:
            torch.Tensor: GradCAM heatmap.
        """
        # Get the target layer from the model's Sequential module
        target_layer = self.model._modules[f"block{target_layer_index}"]

        # Register the backward hook on the target layer
        target_layer.register_backward_hook(self.backward_hook)

        # Forward pass
        output, activations = self.model(input_tensor)

        # Zero out gradients
        self.model.zero_grad()

        # Calculate gradients
        output.backward(torch.ones_like(output))

        # Get the gradients from the backward hook
        gradients = self.gradients

        # Global average pooling
        grad_weights = F.adaptive_avg_pool1d(gradients, 1)

        # Multiply the weights with the activations
        heatmap = torch.mul(activations, grad_weights).sum(dim=2, keepdim=True)

        return heatmap

I get the following error:

<ipython-input-71-afdfac905e59>:12: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  sample_input_tensor = torch.tensor(sample_input, dtype=torch.float32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-afdfac905e59> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 
     17 # Generate the GradCAM heatmap
---> 18 heatmap = gradcam.generate_heatmap(sample_input_tensor, target_layer_index)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     69             if module is None:
     70                 raise RuntimeError("You are trying to call the hook of a dead Module!")
---> 71             return self.hook(module, *args, **kwargs)
     72         return self.hook(*args, **kwargs)
     73 

TypeError: save_grad() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Does anybody know why this is happening?
I tried using keras, but that did not work. I also tried changing the save_grad() functions but nothing seems to work. Maybe I am making some kind of logic error?

The error tells me that save_grad() got given 2 arguments too much. Even though I assume you want to save gradient values, I can't tell what the definition of save_grad() is, since you haven't defined or referenced it anywhere, and I can't find it online. The only thing I am noticing is that you set the gradients to zero after you did the forward pass, but after reading some docs, I am not sure this causes problems and probably doesn't cause the error you currently have.

Aah! Thank you for your answer. I now see that I have not added that function yet. My appologies for my oversight and thank you for your guidance!
